# Error on JSON framework parsing

Tags: ios, json, json-framework

I'm having a problem on parsing a JSON from Google Places.

I have the following code for parsing it:

```
NSString *myRawJson = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-15.815347,-47.9164097&radius=500&types=bank&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyBLY-lBALViJ6ybrgtOqQGhsCDQtsdKsnc"]];

    if ([myRawJson length] == 0) {
        [myRawJson release];
        return;
    }

    SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];

    list = [[parser objectWithString:myRawJson error:nil] copy];

    NSDictionary *results = [myRawJson JSONValue];

    placesLatitudes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *latslngs = [[results objectForKey:@"results"] valueForKey:@"location"];
    NSArray *teste = [latslngs objectForKey:@"location"];

    for (NSDictionary *element in teste)
    {
        NSString *latitude = [element objectForKey:@"lat"];
        NSLog(@"%@", latitude);
    }

    [parser release];
```

The URL request returns the following JSON:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [ "Listagens por \u003ca href=\"http://www.telelistas.net/\"\u003eTelelistas\u003c/a\u003e" ],
   "results" : [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -15.8192680,
               "lng" : -47.9146680
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "1a01f2887f1a70bd430d6a7ffa2a7e46974a1cb7",
         "name" : "Banco Bradesco S/A",
         "reference" : "CnRqAAAAXr_6FCDMlpeVF-E0b3cDxNFGzmS1bYBBGc4v4lKrcusGQPEnx1MXnCJVb3nCVWalu2IOwN9oSVtcXS6_W8JLL_CMhKzkm75UqGt5ShX_s0d4coxOBYsbo66JP1NpF9c5Ua7OxyjepQferD6SbAIjIhIQZ6qcgQT8hqAXtFTuPzuZThoUhrCcxKMRwZq2vl8Sv8LJes7d-no",
         "types" : [ "bank", "finance", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "CRS 511 Bl B s/n lj 15/21 - Brasília"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -15.8177890,
               "lng" : -47.9126370
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "e2c56c8ca6643e0f0cef6bd0405fd8c6a30850ad",
         "name" : "UNIBANCO-União de Bancos Brasileiros S/A",
         "reference" : "CpQBgQAAABkp74S1WF0LfZEhkNj6TUbmiPu2djL81IDnFMJhRR2HDx7336PlRh46q16FwCao290T1smo1wNsGQ-sRVZ_S-MClYUDQzdpaTdNVty0JHBjQTEOMVo0yW8Uzd_OcuI12v8eZ81wu5V7sgHomBw-SeE-mhrPntOU1EzmOANNhIDRExdKmrof2hIKHdLJJaccdRIQeQ9uN-L66Ztmz4_2dkk7DhoUZxcYaZqXgXXnAwWB97e6bNCNp8A",
         "types" : [ "bank", "finance", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "Bl CRS 510 Bl A s/n - Brasília"
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I'm trying to get the information in the path results > geometry > location > lat but I with the code above I get the error:  -[__NSArrayI objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5a526e0.

Someone know how to parse this data using JSON Framework for iOS? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

results is an array, not a dictionary.  location is a dictionary, not an array.

```
NSDictionary *results = [myRawJson JSONValue];

foreach (NSDictionary *result in [results objectForKey:@"results"])
{
    NSDictionary *location = [[result objectForKey:@"geometry"] objectForKey:@"location"];
    NSString *latitude = [location objectForKey:@"lat"];
    NSString *longitude = [location objectForKey:@"lng"];
}
```

I did not test compile that code, but it should be close.

Comment: Another thing to note is that `location` is a dictionary, and therefore must be enumerated using fast enumeration, or the `allKeys` array.

Comment: True, if enumeration was needed, but it's not in this case.

Answer (score 3):

```
Here Parse Data From Google Map API    

-(NSString *)getAddressFromLatLon:(double)pdblLatitude withLongitude:(double)pdblLongitude
    {

        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=%f,%f&sensor=true",pdblLatitude, pdblLongitude];
        NSError* error;
        NSString *locationString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
        // NSLog(@"%@",locationString);

        locationString = [locationString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];


        NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:(requestURL)];

        //response
        NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

        NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
        NSDictionary *locationResults = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];
        if ([locationResults count]==0) {

            [AQHelper showAlert:self withTitle:@"Empty Location" withMessage:@"Location Not Found!"];
            return nil;
        }
        else{

         NSString *fullAddress = [[[locationResults objectForKey:@"results"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"formatted_address"]
        ;

        self.address=fullAddress;

        id allValues = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];


        NSArray *result = [(NSDictionary*)allValues objectForKey:@"results"];

    //    for(int i=0;i<[result count];i++)
    //    {
            NSDictionary *values = (NSDictionary*)[result objectAtIndex:0];

            NSArray *component = [(NSDictionary*)values objectForKey:@"address_components"];

            for(int j=0;j<[component count];j++)
            {
                NSDictionary *parts = (NSDictionary*)[component objectAtIndex:j];
                if([[parts objectForKey:@"types"] containsObject:@"route"])
                {
                    if ([parts objectForKey:@"long_name"]!=0) {
                        self.street=[parts objectForKey:@"long_name"];
                    }
                    else{
                        self.street=[parts objectForKey:@"short_name"];
                    }



                }

                if([[parts objectForKey:@"types"] containsObject:@"locality"])
                {

                    if ([parts objectForKey:@"long_name"]!=0) {
                        self.city=[parts objectForKey:@"long_name"];
                    }
                    else{
                        self.city=[parts objectForKey:@"short_name"];
                    }

                }


                if([[parts objectForKey:@"types"] containsObject:@"administrative_area_level_2"])
                {

                    if ([parts objectForKey:@"long_name"]!=0) {
                        self.state=[parts objectForKey:@"long_name"];
                    }
                    else{
                        self.state=[parts objectForKey:@"short_name"];
                    }

                }

                if([[parts objectForKey:@"types"] containsObject:@"postal_code"])
                {

                    if ([parts objectForKey:@"long_name"]!=0) {
                        self.zip=[parts objectForKey:@"long_name"];
                    }
                    else{
                        self.zip=[parts objectForKey:@"short_name"];
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        return self.address;

    }
```